# SQLite.swift: Use XCGLogger

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift, xcglogger

I'm using `SQLite.swift` library in my iOS project.

Now I'm logging `SQLite` sentences using db.trace(println) as suggested in the documentation, but I want to use the `XCGLogger` library with something like `log.info()`.

Somebody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure and call the `log.info()` function inside of it:

```
db.trace { SQL in
    log.info(SQL)
}
```